# how to build a subversion service?

Tags: linux, svn

I want to build a workspace with subversion, and I followed some tutorials;

1. Install subversion  --OK
2. `svnadmin create /var/svn/repos` --OK
3. rebuild the conf file (delete "#" in passwd,authz,svnserve.conf).
4. sartup the server (`svnserve -d -r /var/svn/repos`) --have no return
5. import something (`svn import /var/svn/import /var/svn/repos`) --also no return
6. test the service (`svn info svn://localhost/var/home/repos`)

--

> svn: warning: W160013: URL 'svn://localhost/var/svn/repos' non-existent in revision 1 svn: E200009: Could not list all targets
>   because some targets don't exist

Which step is wrong? Did I miss something important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path is wrong in step 6. `svnserve` interprets paths as local paths within the repository it is serving. Try this:

```
svn info svn://localhost/
```